# How to sync developer database with central database?

Tags: oracle

How to do that I am using oracle 10 g

Comment: Are you talking about data or schema structure?

Answer (score 2):

You may use Oracle [DataPump utility](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/OracleDataPump10g.php). In my project, this is automated with help of a simple script and Windows scheduled task. The script exports from central DB and then import into dev DB. Depends on your requirements, you may export/import in DB/Schema/Table level.

Answer (score 0):

can you use data guard and take snapshots to work on whenever required?